# WHat happens if I cut the blue wire in my laptop's fan?

Tags: fan

I'm just wondering. I have black, red, yellow, and blue wires on my fan. Will the fan turn off? Will the fan go nuts?
EDIT: The red and black are the power wires.

Comment: Is this like an action movie 'diffuse the bomb' question ??

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the actual specifications, but the likelihood is that it will turn off. There are voltage and control wires. Accordingly, I suggest you do not cut these wires.

Turning off the fan or seriously impairing it could fry your CPU.

Fans are designed in for a purpose, so maintain that purpose to help keep your computer working.

I do electronics work in my basement. Cutting wires to experiment is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Red and black are the power wires.

Comment: It still does not help to remove the control wire.

Comment: I think it is entirely possible that the fan will shut down. It needs to be controlled in the fan circuit.

Comment: It will depend on whether the speed is set by voltage or by resistance. In either case, you'll find out when you cut it whether it will slow or speed… which leads inevitably towards "why on earth do you want to cut it anyway?"

Comment: @54657 - That is normally the case but not always.  Don’t cut the wire…

Answer (score 0):

I did this. BUT DO NOT CUT THE YELLOW WIRE ON YOUR FAN if you cut your fan.
If you cut it it will run the fan speed to CRAZY it and while your laptop is chilling but in full fan throttle you laptop will get slow because you putting more volts on your fan..JUST DONT

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).